# post and trigger a php file in server using jquery ajax post method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

send the values from a javascript file to server side php file and create a file in server side using the jquery ajax post method.

try some code

javascript code

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/export/some.php",
    data: { dataString: "hi" },
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
      alert(dataString);
      this.openDestinationURL();
    }
  });
```

php code as below

```
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0"); 
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Content-Type: text/x-csv");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"search_results.csv\""); 

if($_POST['data']){
  print $_POST['data'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it is working

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/export/some.php",
  data: { dataString: "hi" },
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    this.openDestinationURL();    
  }
});
```

here is the php file

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$data =$_POST["dataString"];

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');//set the path
fputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: how can i saw the data in php file..its show some error while i trigger the php file...

Comment: will help me how to view the php file @SarathSprakash

Comment: Check the code above i have added the php file ok . Hope this helps

Comment: actually i want create and save a csv file in server side. will help me

Comment: I have updated the code. check this. the sample.csv will ve overwritten each time. If you want it to append then open file in append mode

Comment: put php://output in fopen ok.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35265/discussion-between-max25-and-sarathsprakash)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending `data: { dataString: "hi" }`, the actual POST data will be:

```
if(isset($_POST['dataString'])){
  print $_POST['dataString'];
}
```

Also use isset().

As for your AJAX:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/export/some.php",
      data: { dataString: "hi" },
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
          alert(result);
          this.openDestinationURL();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data as multidimensional array

```
$.post('http://localhost/export/some.php', 
    {data: [["aaa","bbb","ccc","dddd"],["123","456","789"],["aaa","bbb"]]}, 
    function(){
        alert('saved');
    }
);
```

On php side just save to file

```
$output = fopen('path to csv file', 'w');
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row, ';');
}
fclose($output);
```

Comment: i want to save csv file in server side

Comment: So change 'path to csv file' and file will be saved on the server. You dont need headers while you dont want to directly download file from web. Then you can use direct link to saved file for downloading it.

Comment: its working thanks but the mutidimensional is in correct format a u set how to insert correctly in csv file.help me.

Comment: What is the source for data? You dont need to send it as array, just send data as string and then parse it in php file.